# jquery serialize - get form field values issue

Tags: jquery, serialization

I am using the serialize function to get the form field values. There is a text area in the form which accepts different values in a new line for e.g.
Option1
Option2
Option3

I want to fetch those values separately but these values comes in a string.

I am using this code to fetch form data ( where event_setting is the form name )

```
jQuery( 'form.event_setting' ).serialize()
```

The serialized data returns as

```
options=option1%2C%0D%0Aoption2%2C%0D%0Aoption3
```

Let me know if require more information. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `serializeArray()` instead , it will return array of form data

```
jQuery( 'form.event_setting' ).serializeArray();
```

**Documentation :** [**http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/**](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Comment: Awesome, thanks !! Seem to be working. I am testing it. Will be back.